# Simple css parsing guidance needed

Tags: c#, vb.net, parsing, css

I'm looking for some guidance on extracting the rules and property/values from a .css file or <style></style>.

I don't need a full blown parser because I don't care if the selector text, property name or property value is valid or not; I just need to make sure that I don't split the text where I shouldn't do and I ignore text within comments etc.

As I say, I'm just looking for guidance but if there is an example in C# or VB then even better.

I would ultimately end up with a collection of rules. Each rule would contain the selector text and a collection of property/value pairs.

I can get this information using the .NET Webbrowser control but unfortunately if it finds a property it recognizes but cannot parse the value, it excludes it. This means that the following would be ignored by the webbrowser control (using IE9):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, green, blue);
```

However, if it doesn't recognize the property, it includes it; so if I modified the line to *-foo-background-image: ..*, it would be picked up.

**As an aside**, will IE10 be available for Win7 when it is released? I'm a little confused by the ms website which seems to imply it will need Win8. I find it hard to believe that one would need Win8 in order to use the -ms-linear-gradient property.

**ETA:** I've added as many assemblies as possible to reflector and had a search through but I cannot find the classes that the .NET framework uses to extract the rules for the css property browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifications for syntax and parsing rules:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-syntax/#syntax

As for IE10, as far as I know, *final* version of it will be available for Windows Vista/7 too.